# Looping with multiple subset() functions in R: Is there a more elegant / quicker way?

Tags: r, loops, subset, mapply

I'm trying to calculate some historic averages on a reasonably large data frame (size 50,000r x 150c) and to do so, I first need to subset the data according to two criteria then apply some arithmetic function to one of the subsetted columns.  I then write the result to another data frame as a new column of counts / averages / weighted averages over certain periods.  Due to the size of the datasets (and the limitations of my coding skill) this is taking a long time and my question is, is there a better way to approach this kind of problem in R?

Here's a simple example to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
library(lubridate)

###  Create dataframe Df

date <- c("01/01/2020", "02/01/2020", "02/01/2020","02/01/2020", "03/01/2020", 
          "03/01/2020", "03/01/2020", "03/01/2020", "04/01/2020", "04/01/2020")
date <- dmy(date)
name <- c("john", "paul", "john", "peter", "peter", 
          "john", "andrew", "john", "peter", "peter")
visits <- c(1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 
            4, 6, 1 ,1, 9)
Df <- data.frame(date, name, visits)
Df


###  Create dataframe Df1

date1 <- c("01/01/2020", "02/01/2020", "03/01/2020", "04/01/2020")
date1 <- dmy(date1)
name1 <- c("john", "paul", "andrew", "peter")
totvisits <- c(0, 0, 0, 0)
Df1 <- data.frame(date1, name1, totvisits)
Df1

Df$name <- as.character(Df$name)
Df1$name1 <- as.character(Df1$name1)
```

In this example I want to (for each row name1/date1 pair in Df1) subset Df according to date / name and return the number of visits each 'name1' has made prior to each 'date1' value ie by summing the 'visits' column for date < date1.  I then want to save this value to the relevant row of a new column ('Df1$totvisits' in this example).  As far as I can tell this requires some kind of loop which on bigger datasets is clunky and takes ages. I've tried mapply() too but that's no quicker and doesn't get away from the fact that my solution isn't very elegant.

```
### loop 
for (i in 1:dim(Df1)[1]) {
  Df1[i, 3] <- sum(subset(Df, Df$name == Df1$name1[i] & Df$date <= Df1$date1[i])[,3])
}
Df1

### apply()
f <- function(x, y) {
  sum(subset(Df, (Df$name == x) & (Df$date <= y))[,3])
  }
Df1[, 3] <- mapply(f, x = Df1$name1, y = Df1$date1)
Df1
```

Any idea or pointers on an alternative approach would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

To make the above clearer, what I'm trying to do is to add a new column to Df1 ('Df1$totvisits') where each entry is the result of looking up date1/name1 in the other data frame ('Df), and returning the sum of the visits that occurred before 'date1' for each 'name1'.  For example, in the "2020-01-02   paul" row in Df1, I need to get values of visits from Df where 'name == paul' and 'date <= 02/01/2020', and then put the sum of them in the third column, second row of Df1.  Since there is only one instance of paul in Df1 with date <= "2020-01-02", this entry becomes = 3.

I would like to be able to extend this to looking up value from a range of dates e.g. dates between x and y where person z has made a visit.  I'd like to do this so that I can calculate visits in an n day window.

In a dplyr context, I think what I'm trying to do is 'mutate' **Df1** with a new column that contains an expression that returns values of sums of **Df**$visits before (/ between) each date.  It's just I cant seem to get it to work and it's driving me nuts.

Thanks in advance for any more help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Still not 100% sure if I understand what you want to do, but here is a `dplyr` way to get:

> In this example I want to (for each row name1/date1 pair in Df1) subset
>   Df according to date / name and return the number of visits each
>   'name1' has made prior to each 'date1' value ie by summing the
>   'visits' column for date < date1.

```
library(dplyr)
Df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(total = cumsum(visits)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(name, date)
```

The code above returns:

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 4
>    date       name   visits total
>    <date>     <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
>  1 2020-01-03 andrew      6     6
>  2 2020-01-01 john        1     1
>  3 2020-01-02 john        2     3
>  4 2020-01-03 john        4     7
>  5 2020-01-03 john        1     8
>  6 2020-01-02 paul        3     3
>  7 2020-01-02 peter       1     1
>  8 2020-01-03 peter       3     4
>  9 2020-01-04 peter       1     5
> 10 2020-01-04 peter       9    14
> ```

And this is how the same task could look like with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
Df <- data.table(Df)
Df[order(date), total:=cumsum(visits), name]
```

We sort it to get the same structure as the solution above:

```
Df[order(name, date),]
```

> ```
>           date   name visits total
>  1: 2020-01-03 andrew      6     6
>  2: 2020-01-01   john      1     1
>  3: 2020-01-02   john      2     3
>  4: 2020-01-03   john      4     7
>  5: 2020-01-03   john      1     8
>  6: 2020-01-02   paul      3     3
>  7: 2020-01-02  peter      1     1
>  8: 2020-01-03  peter      3     4
>  9: 2020-01-04  peter      1     5
> 10: 2020-01-04  peter      9    14
> ```

Comment: And `base` R: `Df <- within(Df[order(Df$name, Df$date),], { total <- ave(visits, name, FUN=cumsum)})`

Comment: @Parfait Perfect! Thanks for showing some love for `base R` ;)

Comment: Thanks very much for both your replies - my first ever question in here so apologies for being unclear.  I would like to update each row of Df1 with the relevant count, so "2020-01-01   john " with 1, "2020-01-02   paul" with 3, "2020-01-03 andrew" and so on.  So four rows with the totals.